# Is there an API to automate uploading of Opera add-ons to addons.opera.com?

Tags: opera-extension

We're currently uploading each new version of our extension via https://addons.opera.com/developer/

Because we need to do similar tasks for Chrome and Firefox, the whole lot becomes tedious and error-prone. Is there a way to automate this, similar to the [Chrome Store Publish API](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/using_webstore_api)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opera Addons Dev here. This panel does operate using REST api.

You can see what requests are being made in the background and try to mimic them.

You need to be authenticated in order to do that though.

Any script that preserves cookies and does authentication in https://auth.opera.com should be fine.

Comment: it's good that you use REST api but your suggestion sounds like "spend a day to deal with our API without docs". So, do you have a plan to make this API public and allow developers easily upload extensions like Chrome does?

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience but currently we don't plan to do that.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment there is no documented API, that doesn't stop us though. I would recommend using the `@wext/shipit` package, which is a command line utility to upload extensions to different providers. It currently supports Chrome WebStore, Mozilla Add-ons (Firefox) and Opera Extensions.

https://github.com/LinusU/wext-shipit

It's a Node.js application, so you can install it with [npm](https://www.npmjs.com).

```
npm install --global @wext/shipit
```

Then you can issue this one command to zip a folder and upload it to addons.opera.com:

```
shipit opera my-extension
```

It will read credentials for the addons.opera.com site from the environment. Make sure that the following variables are populated:

```
# Email and password to log in with
WEXT_SHIPIT_OPERA_EMAIL
WEXT_SHIPIT_OPERA_PASSWORD

# ID of the extension to update
WEXT_SHIPIT_OPERA_EXTENSION_ID
```

If you are only interested in the submitting to Opera, that is handled by the following library:

https://github.com/LinusU/upload-opera-extension

*full disclamer: I'm the author of both packages*